# Firemonkey, C++ Builder, Control-Model-Presentaion, TPresentationProxyFactory registeration Error

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

There is an unresolved external error in calling of register method of `TPresentationProxyFactory`, when passing the template based class `TWinPresentationProxy__1`, as the parameter, `xxx` is a `TWinPresentation` descendant class.

```
TPresentationProxyFactory::Current->Register('xxx', __classid(TWinPresentationProxy__1<xxx>));
```

The error:

> [ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'Fmx::Presentation::Win::TWinPresentationProxy__1::' referenced from C:\USERS\RR\DESKTOP\MDI\MDI\WIN32\DEBUG\GL_PANEL_WIN.OBJ

It is interesting that the Delphi equivalent line of code is working! Also interesting that `TWinPresentationProxy__1` is a `PASCALIMPLEMENTATION` class?

Comment: Sorry, correct line of code,  TPresentationProxyFactory::Current->Register('xxx', __classid(TWinPresentationProxy__1<xxx>));

Comment: Error Message, [ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'Fmx::Presentation::Win::TWinPresentationProxy__1<WinGLPanel>::' referenced from C:\USERS\RR\DESKTOP\MDI\MDI\WIN32\DEBUG\GL_PANEL_WIN.OBJ